# Multiple views in blank ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework

In index.html I have included these javascripts:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

And then I have:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

In app.js I have this:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
});
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('view.splash', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
        'view.splash': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/view-splash.html',
            controller: 'SplashCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state('view.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
          'view.login': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/view-login.html',
              controller: 'LoginCtrl'
          }
      }
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

});
```

And finally in controllers.js I have:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('SplashCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.appname = 'Wetters';
})

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.whereami = 'on login';
})
```

Now, splash.html looks like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Splash">
<ion-content>
    This is splash
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

However, when I go to the app with browser, nothing is displayed. The page is empty.
I don't really understand whats wrong.
On ionic-page they don't write much about blank pages, focus is most on tab or menu apps.
What should you put inside index.html when you want to view multiple views, one at the time? I think the problem could be Im using:

```
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

Maybe I should put something else in index, but I really dont know what to put there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a example for you:

[Splash and Login example](http://codepen.io/lcszulpo/pen/xVgrae?editors=1011)

If you need some help, just call!

Here is the code, if you cannot see in codepen:

HTML

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
```

```
<title>Side Menus</title>

<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

```
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

<script id="templates/splash.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Splash" ng-controller="SplashCtrl">
    <ion-content>
      Splash
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/login.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Login" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <ion-content>
       Login
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

JS

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('splash', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "templates/splash.html"
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html"
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
})

.controller('SplashCtrl', function($scope, $state, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function() {
     $state.go('login');
  }, 3000);
})

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works. But I dont really understand a couple of things. You put content for login and splash inside html. If I have a lot of views then index would be filled with too much code. Its not that good. Also, in app.js you refer to "templateUrl" in templates-folder. However, they are never used. Why? What I need is just to let content be in templates folder. Thanks again.

Comment: I make like this only for the example. You can put all what are in <script id="templates/splash.html"... in a file inside /templates.

Comment: In this case, templateUrl are referring id="templates/login.html"